# Simplifying the integral $\int \frac{1}{x^2+36}\,dx$ using the substitution $x = 6\tan t$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Use the substitution $x = 6\tan t$, to simplify the following integral: $$\int \frac{1}{x^2+36}\,dx.$$

Comment: What are your efforts ?   At least show us the first step and simplification.

Comment: I downvoted. This seems pretty straightforward: not to criticize your abilities, but solving it is just a matter of reading the chapter about substitutions in your calculus book and mechanically applying the given hint; this question shows no effort whatsoever.

Comment: I have downvoted too. Also flagged the question for closure. We should not be giving out answers on a platter.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, let $x=6\tan t\implies dx=6\sec^2 t\ dt$

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+36}\ dx=\int\frac{1}{36\tan^2t+36}(6\sec^2 t \ dt)$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\int\frac{\sec^2 t}{\tan^2t+1}\  dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\int\frac{\sec^2 t}{\sec^2t}\  dt$$$$=\frac{1}{6}\int \ dt=\frac{1}{6}(t)+C$$
substituting value of $t$, 
$$=\frac{1}{6}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{6}\right)+C$$